# FreeRADIUS 3.0.18 // EAP-FAST

Tags: windows, freeradius

Ciao. I was tasked with testing FR and EAP-FAST. For some unknown reason it is not working with the latest version (3.0.18). However exactly the same configuration and user works fine with version 3.0.16.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

[EAP-FAST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCVzU.png)

Comment: You'd have to post your debug output so we can see where it's failing. The original EAP-FAST code had some pretty severe quality issues with it, it's possible that some of the work to fix the initial problems has broken it, especially as the original author never integrated it with our EAP test suite so it doesn't run under CIT.

Comment: I did try to append/attach the debug output but Stackoverflow wouldn't allow it (too long, I guess)